# Etymology of "Haggard" has anything to do with Hagar in Islam?

Tags: english, etymology

A simple google search tells me that "Haggard" emerged in...

```
...mid 16th century (used in falconry): from French hagard ; perhaps related to 
hedge; later influenced by hag.
```

However, on a Discovery Channel program recently, I got to know about Hagar. She was the wife of the patriarch and Islamic prophet Ibrāhīm (Abraham) and the mother of the Ismā'īl (Ishmael).

She...

```
...was stranded in a desert, and ran between the Al-Safa and Al-Marwah hills in 
search of water for her son. After the seventh run between the two hills, an 
angel appeared before her. He helped her and told her that God had heard   
Ishmael's crying and would provide them with water.
```

I cannot help but wonder, the english word "haggard" meaning -

```
"looking exhausted and unwell, especially from fatigue, worry, or suffering."
```

...could easily have emerged from the story of Hagar as even she must have been exhausted.

Is there any way to be sure?

PS: all information from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagar_in_Islam.

Comment: Do you realise that Hagar is mentioned already in the Old Testament (Hebrew Bible)? I don't see why you want to construct an Islamic connection.

Comment: Why are you trying to bring in a religious angle here? I would have downvoted you had I the required amount of reputation.

I simply said I saw a Discovery program, I have no idea about any other history with respect to Hagar.

Comment: Welcome to linguistics.SE, Yuganka Sharan. Why would you think there is any connection between the two? I'm no etymologist, but there seem to be *worlds* separating the two words... Also, they are not that complex phonologically... There is actually even a facebook group all about linguistic coincidences - your discovery sounds like something that could come up there. I'd wait for an expert's answer, though.

Comment: @maj That is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. "...want to construct an Islamic connection" from the previous commenter seems almost like I am out here with an agenda. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no etymological connection between the two. In English, [-*ard*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ard) and -*art* are suffixes, used in the formation of many words. The word suggests *hag* as a root, and is related to the German *hag(er)*, having a similar meaning. (In German, -*er* is also a suffix).